# Clean way to add user if it doesn't exist

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, redux, ngrx

I want to add a user to my users array if the user doesn't exist but if it doesn't exist I don't want anything to change. Normally to do this I would do this:

```
users: {...state.users, newUser}
```

But this is not possible because I don't have a property name in this case.

So my user looks like this:

```
export interface IUser {
  username: string;
  deviceCode: string;
  deviceName: string;
}

state.users: IUser[];
```

And what I did to solve this problem is this:

```
case AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS: {
  const currentUser: IUser = {
    username: state.username,
    deviceCode: action.payload.deviceCode,
    deviceName: action.payload.deviceName,

  };

  const userExists = state.users.find((user) => user.username === state.username);
  let users = state.users;
  if (!userExists) {
    users = {...state.users, ...[currentUser]}
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    deviceCode: action.payload.deviceCode,
    deviceName: action.payload.deviceName,
    users,
  };
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't feel clean enough for me and a reducer should always be as clean as possible. Is there a way to make `users: {...state.users, newUser}` work? If not, is there another good way to do this?

In short:

```
case AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS: {
  // I don't want to write any code here
  return {
    ...state,
    deviceCode: action.payload.deviceCode,
    deviceName: action.payload.deviceName,
    users: {...state.users, newUser}, // Add new user if it doesn't exist, 
                                      // Change if it is different 
                                      // Do nothing if it is the same
  };
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand the question and want to report it for more focus that's fine. But tell me what you don't understand about it.

Comment: I do not see a technical question here. What are you stuck on *specifically*? As it is written now this seems like a requirement where you need help writing the implementation which would be considered to broad for [so].

Comment: Specifically I want to change the property users within my REGISTER_SUCCESS action. If the user is new, I want to add the user to the array. If it is different, I want to change the different properties only. If it is the same, I want to change nothing. I want to implement this using `{...state.users, newUser: IUser}` But that doesn't work because IUser doesn't have an index. If I do add an index to it it will be unique and not the same as the index of the existing user.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do this the right way is this:

```
case AuthActionTypes.REGISTER_SUCCESS: {
  const currentUser = [];
  currentUser[state.username] = {
    deviceCode: action.payload.deviceCode,
    deviceName: action.payload.deviceName,

  };
  return {
    ...state,
    deviceCode: action.payload.deviceCode,
    deviceName: action.payload.deviceName,
    users: {...state.users, ...currentUser}
  };
}
```

Since the property name is now equal to the username I can always assign it to the username which will add if it doesn't exist, edit if it is different, and do nothing if it is the same.

I think this answer makes my question even more specific so if you have a better answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: You could have changed the iUser interface into a Class with a constructor that set all the properties to null. Then you could have used sers: {...state.users, new newUser()}

Comment: Ah yes that might actually be more useful than an interface in this case.